# How do I create a Grid that behaves more like a Stack or a Table?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to create a Grid using Material-UI that act similarly to a table, where there's an even spacing that separates the left and right columns. So for example, the grid should look like this:

```
Name:            John Doe
Date of Birth:   1/1/2000
Phone Number:    123456789
Email:           john@email.com
```

How I set it up is as shown below:

```
<Grid container>
  <Grid item xs={4}>
    <Box sx={styles.grid}>
      <Typography sx={styles.title}>Name</Typography>
      <Typography sx={styles.title}>Date of Birth</Typography>
      <Typography sx={styles.title}>Phone Number</Typography>
      <Typography sx={styles.title}>Email</Typography>
    </Box>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={8}>
    <Box sx={styles.grid}>
      <Typography sx={styles.content}>{name}</Typography>
      <Typography sx={styles.content}>{dob}</Typography>
      <Typography sx={styles.content}>{phone}</Typography>
      <Typography sx={styles.content}>{email}</Typography>
    </Box>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The problem is that if an element is missing, it doesn't leave an empty space and rather that space is taken by the next element. If say phone number is missing, it ends up looking like this:

```
Name:            John Doe
Date of Birth:   1/1/2000
Phone Number:    Email:
john@email.com
```

I tried using the Stack component instead, which behaves more like I want it to, but the spacing between the left and right elements are not even between rows, even with styling.

```
Name:  John Doe
Date of Birth:  1/1/2000
Phone Number:  123456789
Email:  john@email.com
```

Would putting the typography inside a box with a set size be ideal in this case or is there an alternative? Perhaps I'm not using the right props?